# how to link title and extract of a blog dynamically onclick to it's large content to another page in PHP and mysql database

Tags: php, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

here is my Index.php code which contains the title, extract, and an image of each article of a blog displaying in the index.php page which is my home page.  I want the title of each article to have a link to its large content to be displayed to another page which is at the same table database. I don't know how to figure it out.
any help will be appreciated. bythe way I am an absolute beginner.

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/dbconfig.php';


try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

    $sql = 'SELECT  title, publish_date, extract, image


               FROM articles
              ORDER BY id';

    $q = $pdo->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
<?php
echo $row['id'].
$row['title'].
$row['extract'];

?>">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>blog</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></a>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/chic.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>My Blog</h2>
        </div>


        <header>
           <nav>


              <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="includes/testing.php">Page Billet blog</a></li>
                 <li><a href="includes/check/index.php?login">Login</a></li>
                 <!-- <li></li> -->

              </ul>
           </nav>
        </header>

                    <?php while($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
                        //here is my update
                   <a href="includes/articles.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'].$row['content']; ?>
                      <?php $s=$row['image']; ?>
                      <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="leftcolumn">
                          <div class="card">
                          <h1 class="title"> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']); ?> </h1>
                          <h5 class="publish_date">  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['publish_date']); ?> </h5>
                          <p class="extract">  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['extract']); ?> </p>
                          <div class="fakeimg"><?php echo '<img src="'.$s.'" issue displaying img >';?></div>
                      </div>
                      </div>




                    <?php endwhile; ?>




    </body>
</html>
```

and here is articles.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>blog</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/articles.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>My Blog</h2>
        </div>






              <?php  $id = $_GET['id']; ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the `<a href...` inside the `while loop`. You'll also have select `id` in your query.

Comment: thanks for your comment but could you give me a litle more hint please?

Comment: inside another page how  to write id query ? to have a link with a href of index.php

Comment: as you mentioned, I have written the <a href... inside the while loop in index.php but in another page how to call my a href to have a link?

Comment: Update your code to show the latest changes. Your link would point to a details page. `... <a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>...`. Then, on the details page, you can get it by `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: And, your link should look like `<h1><a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></h1>`.

Comment: thanks a lot man. I am almost there. you are awesome!

Comment: No prob. BTW you cannot access `$row` outside of the `while` loop because that is where you are defining it - `while($row = $q->fetch()):`